# How can I pass a variable between two Perl CGI programs without a form?

Tags: forms, perl, parameters, web, cgi

I'm creating a website in Perl containing CGI which has a login side to it. Problem is, is that I am struggling to pass parameters without a form (don't particularly want to use a form to navigate between pages). The parameter I want to pass is the username.

The only solution I can see is to use a form submit button for the navigation bar, and then to make a text field hidden, containing the variable that holds the username. But there must be an alternative method.

Is there any way I can pass this parameter without usage of a form continuously throughout different pages until the user logs off (or quits the website).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a form?

Comment: Using a form would mean that I would have to press a 'submit' button to pass these parameters. To follow the design of the website, I would have to replace navigation buttons with submit buttons.

Comment: What's the problem? What do forms even have to do with requesting a web page?

Comment: Problem: User logs in, clicks on a link, username forgotten. Getting the web page up isn't a problem, it's the web pages remembering the username which is the problem.

Comment: See: [CGI::Cookie](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI/Cookie.pm) or pass parameters in your links. Or, better yet, use a framework like Catalyst which handles all of this for you.

Comment: Easy: Use a cookie to store the information. Better: Use a cookie to store a session id that allows you to locate the correct information server-side.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll give those a go.